# Angularjs - 720kb.datepicker - Open calendar manually

Tags: angularjs

I am using 720kb.datepicker for to show a calendar. I want to open the calendar from a link in manual way.

This is html code:

```
<datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateBirth"
      id="date-birth" name="dateBirth" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY" required maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/"
      validator="isDateofBirthMore" />
    <span>open calendar</span>
</datepicker>
```

I want to open the calendar when i have done  clik in text "open calendar"

I'm trying to focus on this documentation, but i cannot get it:
http://pythonhackers.com/p/720kb/angular-datepicker

Specifically in this section: Manually show and hide datepicker

How could do it? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also use datepicker-toggle in tandem with datepicker-show.  Here [is my updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LCQfG9hvANHYnbAcC5Ku?p=preview)

I am not very sure that they have handled all events looking at the source code.  You may have to use jQuery and $(window).on('blur click', function(){}) and $('#spanId').on('blur click', function(){}), etc for the span, window to get this completely working.

> controller:

```
        var app = angular.module('plunker', ['720kb.datepicker']);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval, $window) {
          $scope.visibility = false;
          $scope.toggled = false;


          $scope.toggle = function(){
            $scope.visibility = !$scope.visibility;
            $scope.toggled = !$scope.toggled;
          }

        });
```

> HTML:

```
        <datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" datepicker-toggle="false" datepicker-show="{{ visibility }}">
          <!-- Use flag for visibility -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-birth" name="dateBirth" required="" ng-model="dateBirth" placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/" validator="isDateofBirthMore" />
          <!-- Set flag = true on click -->
          <span id="openMe" ng-click="toggle()">open calendar</span>
        </datepicker>
```

Toggle on/off works only by clicking on the span.  You can use change the span text to read open/close upon toggle, if firing events doesn't do for you.

Comment: It was a big help, thank you very much, it is what i want. And now i will investigate how to close the calendar when i do click outside input field ;).

Comment: I am glad that you found a solution to this usecase.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Just use a flag for keeping track of the visibility:

```
<datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            datepicker-show="{{ showDatepicker }}"> <!-- Use flag for visibility -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-birth" name="dateBirth"
           required
           ng-model="dateBirth"
           placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY" 
           maxlength="10"
           ng-pattern="/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/"
           validator="isDateofBirthMore" />
    <!-- Toggle flag on click -->
    <span ng-click="showDatepicker = !showDatepicker">open calendar</span>
</datepicker>
```

Comment: datapicker still opens when you click on the textbox.  Manually means old-fashioned, point-n-click.  Worst is once you open it by clicking the span element it never can be closed!, of course you can have a toggle.  Doesn't seem to be straightforward except to stop that event from being propagated - $event.on

Comment: The question does not say anything about 'not on clicking textbox'. The question is how to open the datepicker when clicking on the `span` element, which is exactly what this answer provides. Of course I would implement it somewhat else, but this just straight answers the question

Comment: "I want to open the calendar when i have done clik in text "open calendar""  - To me, the words "I have done click" means, unless I click, which is when I am done, don't do anything, not even opening the popup, if it is the default behavior.  I am reading the sentence correct.

Comment: Exactly if I put the link above on input field, opens the calendar, then does not introduces the date inside the input field and when i am doing clic outside input field doesn't close the calendar, I will continue investigating.

Comment: In real, i dont need that the calendar opens when execute the focus event, the calendar only must to be open when i do click in text "open calendar". It should be working like the default way the only one diference is that the calendar opens from another link.